# How to display words as per given number of letters?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have created this basic script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/usr/share/dict/words"
var=2
sed -n "/^$var$/p" /usr/share/dict/words
```

However, it's not working as required to be (or still need some more logic to put in it).

Here, it should print only 2 letter words but with this it is giving different output

Can anyone suggest ideas on how to achieve this with sed or with awk?

Comment: By the way, the `$file` variable looks useless here, since you are not using it later on in the `sed` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are executing is:

```
sed -n "/^2$/p" /usr/share/dict/words
```

This means: all lines consisting in exactly the number 2, nothing else. Of course this does not return anything, since `/usr/share/dict/words` has words and not numbers (as far as I know).

If you want to print those lines consisting in two characters, you need to use something like `..` (since `.` matches any character):

```
sed -n "/^..$/p" /usr/share/dict/words
```

To make the number of characters variable, use a quantifier `{}` like (note the usage of `\` to have sed's BRE understand properly):

```
sed -n "/^.\{2\}$/p" /usr/share/dict/words
```

Or, with a variable:

```
sed -n '/^.\{'"$var"'\}$/p' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Note that we are putting the variable outside the quotes for safety (thanks Ed Morton in comments for the reminder).

Comment: `+1`. FWIW I always try to localize shell variable expansion as much as possible, e.g. `sed -n '/^.\{'"$var"'\}$/p'` to avoid any surprises when the rest of the script is interpreted by the shell.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks! What could happen in such situation? I mean, in which conditions could my approach have an unexpected behaviour?

Comment: your particular script would be fine, it's just in general best to protect against issues. Like quoting shell variables - in many cases it doesn't matter but it's best to get into the habit of doing it for those times when it does matter.

Answer (score 4):

> it should print only 2 letter words

Your `sed` command is just searching for lines with `2` in text.

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'length() == 2' file
```

Or using a shell variable:

```
awk -v n=$var 'length() == n' file
```

Comment: just great with awk length function

Comment: length by default works on `$0`, so can also use `awk 'length==n'`

Comment: Very good point @Sundeep. I forgot about this, edited it now.

Comment: just looked up [gawk doc for length](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-length_0028_0029-function)... `length()` is recommended

Answer (score 2):

Pure bash... :)

```
file="/usr/share/dict/words"
var=2

#building a regex
str=$(printf "%${var}s")
re="^${str// /.}$"

while read -r word
do
    [[ "$word" =~ $re ]] && echo "$word"
done < "$file"
```

It builds a regex in a form `^..$` (the number of dots is variable). So doing it in 2 steps:

- create a string of the desired length e.g: `%2s`. without args the `printf` prints only the filler spaces for the desired length e.g.: `2`
- but we have a variable `var`, therefore `%${var}s`
- replace all spaces in the string with `.`

but don't use this solution. It is too slow, and here are better utilities for this, best is imho `grep`.

```
file="/usr/share/dict/words"
var=5

grep -P "^\w{$var}$" "$file"
```

Comment: +1 for bash script with regex, but can you please explain regex variable
str=$(printf "%${var}s") -> why s is there at last?
re="^${str// /.}$" -> here, how many spaces given 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

Try `awk`-

```
awk -v var=2 '{if (length($0) == var) print $0}' /usr/share/dict/words
```

This can be shortened to

```
awk -v var=2 'length($0) == var' /usr/share/dict/words
```

which has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

To output only lines matching 2 alphabetic characters with grep:

```
grep '^[[:alpha:]]\{2\}$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk and mawk at least (due to empty `FS`):

```
$ awk -F '' 'NF==2' /usr/share/dict/words                  #| head -5
aa
Ab
ad
ae
Ah
```

Empty `FS` separates each character on its own field so `NF` tells the record length.